# Some weird users in database

Tags: database, users

I've noticed that I have some users that seem fraudulent in my database (in the wp_users column). And the curious thing is that they don't appear in the users list in the admin panel.

How could this happen?

many thanks

Comment: I doubt you'll get any useful answer to this question - you might need to give some extra information about your website, how it works, what features it has and what you have tested so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be this is due to the Spam. Diable use registration under the `General -> Settings` if you don't need registration on the front-end or use the `captcha` or other `spam` protection plugins.

Regarding the backend -> Have you checked the wp_usermeta table if any role assigned to those users or not? Check user roles for those users.

Comment: thanks. the role assigned is "subscriber".